# Combining free text and object ids with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

The following index will allow free text searches on the given model's attributes:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :firm, :with => :active_record do
  indexes activity
  indexes city
end
```

for a form that allows input in `<%= text_field :firm_search, :terms, :size => 35 %>`

However, this class belongs_to :province, thus has a `province_id` column and class Province has a `:name` attribute that could be composed of more than one, hopefully, searchable word.  Can `province.name` be integrated into this free text search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference associations within your index definition:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :firm, :with => :active_record do
  indexes activity
  indexes city
  indexes province.name, :as => :province_name
end
```

Once you've added this, you'll need to run the `ts:rebuild` rake task to have the data included in your Sphinx indices.

Comment: side question.  the syntax appears pre-rails4-ish & I am trying to uniform my syntactic usage.  would `as: :province_name`  run just as well?

Comment: Yes, they're exactly the same. I used the older hash-rocket `=>` syntax because it's what you used in your question (it's also what I prefer, because symbols always get their `:` prefix - but I try to match questioner styles).

Comment: thank you for the consistency.  And pointing out mine that was lurking!